# How to do transform a tree using Scrap Your Boilerplate?

Tags: haskell, tree, traversal

I am new to Haskell, so I am trying to figure out how to do tree traversals.

Here is the Company example (with a slight change) that I have seen in several papers

```
data Company  = C [Dept]               deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable, Data)
data Dept     = D Name Manager [Unit]  deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable, Data)
data ThinkTank= TK Name [Unit]         deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable, Data)
data Unit     = PU Employee | DU Dept  deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable, Data)
data Employee = E Person Salary        deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable, Data)
data Person   = P Name Address         deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable, Data)
data Salary   = S Float                deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable, Data)
type Manager  = Employee
type Name     = String
type Address  = String
```

What I would like to do is move a Employee from where he is to a particular department.  This person could be in a Department or a ThinkTank.

It seems easy to do things in SYB as long as you are doing one type, but I am not sure how to deal with multiple data types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need   to start with an SYB tutorial,

- http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/bin/view/GenericProgramming/SYB

The main traversal functions are:

- http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/stable/docs/libraries/syb/Data-Generics-Schemes.html#v%3Aeverywhere
- http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/stable/docs/libraries/syb/Data-Generics-Schemes.html#v%3Asomewhere

Play around with those  to get a sense for the API, and you'll work it out.

SYB generics is a bit more than a beginner Haskell exercise though.

Answer (score 8):

The tutorial at cs.uu.nl seems to have disappeared. I struggled for a while with this, combing through papers, then wrote [this tutorial](http://expressiveprogramming.com/presentations/syb_talk.html). Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with SYB so I'll show an example using [uniplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate) instead. The example only removes the employee unit from its dept or think tank but you'shll probly easily figure out how to extend it to do what you want.

```
> let jack = E (P "Jack" "The Road") (S 7)
> import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data
> transformBi (filter (/= PU jack)) $ C [D "Operations" (E (P "Charles" "Seattle") (S 700000)) [PU jack]]
C [D "Operations" (E (P "Charles" "Seattle") (S 700000.0)) []]
```